# How to fix Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I am getting the following error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 81 bytes) in
>   /home/public_html/hol/wp-includes/template.php on line 441

and sometimes in

> /home/public_html/hol/wp-includes/template.php

also

I have increased the memory size, but when trying with `define ('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '-1');` it dumps the sever, but nothing happening.

Please can someone suggest why I am getting this issue and how to resolve this issue.

This is getting in My Team plugin by b4u in single team member page..

Comment: I'd be more worried in trying to figure out what's running that that needs more than 256meg of ram...

Comment: when I was asked to my webhost he said that any query is running which consume whole memory. No solution found by increasing the size.

I am using the acevision theme and My team plugin. there are 51 members.